# C++ - After running while loop with cin, the program won't take input again

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, cin

I am running a while loop that will take floats entered by users and add them together until something else is put in the input.

```
while(cin >> input)
{
    price += input;
    cout << "Next price: ";
}
```

After this, I have the user input how much they paid:

```
cout << "Enter the amount paid: ";
cin >> paid;
cout << "You paid: " << paid << endl;
```

When running the program, the loop executes fine, and I can get it to `cout` the total price correctly, but it skips the `cin >> paid;` line and will output as `You paid: nan`.

I tried putting `cin.clear()` between the loop and the next input, but then upon running it, the output was: `You paid: 0`

Do I need to change my while loop or use a different version to clear input? I'm pretty new to C++. Thanks!

Comment: I see many issues with that code. Take a look at this article on how to get data from cin while being type-safe: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

Comment: Take a look at `getline(..)`.

Comment: The "something else" entered by the user is still waiting in the input buffer. You have to remove it before reading another number, like `paid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `cin.clear()`, it resets the error flags. However, the data in the stream are still there. You'll need to ignore the rest of the line before trying to read `paid`.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Make sure to add `#include <limits>` to use `std::numeric_limits`